# Is it better to do a select count then if before doing a delete or just blindly call delete?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, kettle

I'm looking for a best practice / thoughts on if it is better to do a select count and checking if the result is > 0 before calling a delete or if it would be better to just blindly fire a delete statement at the database even if the data doesn't exist.  In our case most of the time data will NOT exist.

So what is better:

```
Option 1: call Select Count(X) where foo, if result > 0, delete where foo
```

or

```
Option 2: delete where foo
```

I lean towards the blind delete for speed reasons and since you are doing a table hit anyways.

EDIT: This is actually happening in kettle(an ETL tool) so the three operations will be done completely separate if there is a delete.  So completely in SQL is not an option.

Comment: If you are in a production database, don't do these kinds of job (Oh yeah, they made me do this once.) If you are in development, I'll go with option 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just delete, if you try to delete something that is not there, it will just delete 0 (zero) rows.  This reduces the amount of trips to the DB as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would say I would do the delete blindly, and then get back the number of rows affected.
In either cases, the comparison is done, it should be almost the same execution time.

Answer (score 2):

Just go for the delete. There is no advantage in issuing a count(*) beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

The universal IT answer is prefaced with "It Depends"

Here it depends on the query plan of the Delete.

If you do an EXISTS query (per OMG-Ponies) that uses an index or a better query plan, that would be better-faster.

An unneeded delete that uses a table scan could then perhaps be avoided.

Comment: Both of the where clauses would be exactly the same, I would believe that they should use the same index or table scan when there isn't one.

Comment: Yes, I agree if the select is identical to the delete.

What I didn't express fully there was: if you understand the structure of the data, you may be able to write query with identical results that uses a better query plan.